# need proper path of SD card in android

Tags: java, android, storage

I'm a window developer but want to develop android application :-)
I am using ADT eclipse to take some trials.
Awesome technology , interface and interesting.

But while taking my first trial related to SD card the following code work perfect fo Samsung galaxy fit.

```
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "QCVerification"+ File.separator+"List of Entries.csv");
```

Okay, I thought its even more interested because my first attempt was successful ;-)

Now for little bit test ,
I tried same application on Samsung galaxy tab.

This gives me an exception like,

**/mnt/sdcard/QCVerification/List of Entry.csv (No such file or directory)**

:-( Now only one cross verification gives me this Error.

So please provide me any link, block of code, project, sample or any suggestion that may help me to find external storage card on any android device. :-)

Comment: this gives you an exception because there's no such directory. So make sure if there is any such directory, if there's not then create a one. It would be better if you make sure when your application runs that the directory exist.

Comment: issue is not that file is present or not issue is that storage directory changes from device to devide..

Comment: Can you make sure if there's any directory mnt/sdcard/QCVerification/List of Entry.csv in Galaxy Tab?

Comment: i will make sure still External storage device + "QCVerification/List of Entry.csv" Because...mnt/sdcard is valid for samsung galaxy fit and not for galaxy tab..

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this exception because probably there exists no such directory / file at all. 
Ensure that such file exists.

Also, you could check if file exists or not with following code:

```
File file = "Your file path";
if(file.exists()){
  // Read File
}
else{
  // Show error message
}
```

You can find more methods related to files [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html)

To get the root of the external storage directory:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Comment: thanks for reply but need solution that gives me storage directory for any device..

Answer (score 0):

```
 File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "QCVerification"+ File.separator+"List of    ntries.csv");
 if(myFile.exists()){
    // do what you wanted to do.
 }
else{
   myFile.mkdirs(); //it will make a directory if it doesn't exists and a file in that directory.
 }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: yes it will work if my file is not present in sd card..But file is present but SD card directoy is change